# Dynamic Plotting with IpyWidgets

Tags: matplotlib, ipywidgets

So I'm trying to create a cell that refreshes plots using a slider.
Here is the code,

```
slider = FloatSlider(0.1)
slider.max = 1
slider.min = 0
plt.plot(figsize=(15,10))

def plot_corr_graph_summary(lod):
    plt.clf()
    corrMatrix_Crushed = df_summary_virtual_physical_split.iloc[:,int(lod):].corr()
    sns.heatmap(corrMatrix_Crushed, annot=False)
    plt.show()

def level_of_detail(change):
    if slider.value >= 0.2:
        plot_corr_graph_summary(6-slider.value*10)

slider.observe(level_of_detail, 'value')
slider
```

The result looks like,

[image: Output]

How do I make the plots overwrite one another, I am trying to use plt.clf() in my function but nothing seems to be happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

using

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
```

The cell output is HTML! Need to flush that, not the plot.

```
clear_output()
```

Will do the trick.